# Query returns fewer fields depending on credentials

Tags: caml-query

I inherited some code that reads in all the files from a Document Library for processing. The existing production library is a standard library bound to an InfoPath form. A new version of this library is based on custom Content Types which are also bound to the same InfoPath form.

Somehow, if I run the query against the new library, I get back different numbers of fields depending on which account I use to connect with. Yet, the same code, with the same credentials, against the existing library returns the same each time.

To make it even more odd, one of the fields not being returned is the Author field but the Editor field is included.

Here are the numbers

**Legacy Library**

My Account     74 fields

Test Account   74 fields

**New Library**

My Account     86 fields

Test Account   **84** fields

(Yes...the new library does indeed have more fields than the legacy library.)

Here is the code

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(SearchKbLoader.Properties.Settings.Default.SharePointWebUrl)) {
    Web web = context.Web;

    var credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchKbLoader.Properties.Settings.Default.SharePointUserLogin)) {
        credentials = new NetworkCredential(
            SearchKbLoader.Properties.Settings.Default.SharePointUserLogin,
            SearchKbLoader.Properties.Settings.Default.SharePointUserPassword,
            SearchKbLoader.Properties.Settings.Default.SharePointUserDomain
            );
    }

    context.Credentials = credentials;

    ListCollection collList = web.Lists;
    var oList = collList.GetByTitle(SearchKbLoader.Properties.Settings.Default.SharePointLibraryName);

    var camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml = @"
        <View>
            <Query>
                <Where>
                    <And>
                        <Gt>
                            <FieldRef Name='Created' />
                            <Value Type='DateTime'>1960-05-10T10:00:00Z</Value>
                        </Gt>
                        <Contains>
                            <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
                            <Value Type='Text'>xml</Value>
                        </Contains>
                    </And>
                </Where>
                <RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
            </Query>
        </View>";

    ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

    context.Load(collListItem,
            items => items.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(
            item => item.DisplayName));

    context.ExecuteQuery();
```

I thought maybe it was the default view but using both accounts I verified that the Author field is shown.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm thinking something's up with the content types involved. Just brainstorming here mixed with questions:
Old library not based on custom content types?
Content types in new library using different base content type?
Does one of the involved content types come from a content type hub, was changed in the old library and never republished?

Comment: I agree...it has to do with the Content Type since that is the only "difference" I can think of. The older system does not have a content type. All they did was create a standard document library, and then publish an InfoPath form directly to the library. The new instance has a library that inherits from the basic version and a content type with an associated InfoPath form. Why that would return a reduced set of fields for a given user...no idea...